# magento 2 affects of attributes and attribute sets on speed

Tags: magento2.2.6, pagespeed

I am working on new magento 2.2.6 site from stracth and need to design attribute sets and its attribute.

I am quite confused about how can we design attributes that won't affect speed of size or minimum affects to speed.

We have 13 attributes set and many attributes are common to attributes sets. for example size attribute falls under 3 to 4 attribute sets.

Can we create more attributes and have minimum number of attributes under particular attribute sets which might takes less load of speed.

Are there any one who knows best setup of attributes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, @Amit, Magento specifically has designed for this nice thing that you can able to create as much as of attributes and attribute sets.

It doesn't go to impact on the speed of the site as i.e you have created 10 attribute sets so it's not generally used 10 at once in the frontend.

It may little cause in search but you can nicely organize via a limited attribute in the search condition.

I hope this will help you a little bit :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have one attribute could have 100 options. does it affect the speed?